# How to generate calendar image like on ios

Tags: c#, .net

where the image is changed to today's date in .net/c#

looking to generate the image used for the calendar icon

hoping it's not too very difficult ??

UPDATE - looking to do this for the desktop/WPF though can take other .net code and change it as needed

sorry for the bother guys, i do biz apps, not good at graphics !

Comment: need some more information... desktop?  web?  Windows Phone?  Win 8 Metro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exact, but it is close:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="CalendarTemplate">
            <Grid Width="220" Height="220">
                <Grid.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.515" ShadowDepth="8" Direction="278" BlurRadius="28"/>
                </Grid.Effect>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="64"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Background="Red" CornerRadius="25,25,0,0" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DayOfWeek}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="32" FontFamily="Arial"/>
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="0,0,25,25">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Day}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="140" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static System:DateTime.Now}}" ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource CalendarTemplate}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

Comment: that's great. the `7` is a little *broken* but it's really close. Just out of curiosity, how do you inject the weekday and the date into your code?

Comment: I'm not sure why the 7 is broken like that.  Must be a font rendering issue.  Weird.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
This answer was given before the OP explained the desired platform. I'm choosing to leave it up since it is helpful to others looking to achieve the same thing in the WEB world.

---

<strike>Since the OP hasn't said what platform this is for</strike>, I'm going to throw out a WEB solution.

Personally I dispise building anything on the server that can be offloaded to the client. Here's a CSS3 way to achieve what is asked.

```
<style>
/* Calendar */

.calendar {
    margin: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    width:176px;
    height:176px;
}

.calendar .header {
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 30px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EEC4C4), to(#521B1C), color-stop(.92,#da3434),color-stop(.1,#ef9fa5));
    height: 50px;
    width: 176px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}

.calendar p.weekday {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    width: 176px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}

.calendar p.daynumber {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
    width: 176px;
    line-height: 126px;
    font-size: 130px;
    text-align: center;
}

.calendar .paper {
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#7A7A7A), to(#EDEDED), color-stop(.05,#BFBFBF),color-stop(.2,#E3E3E3));
    height: 126px;
    width: 176px;
}​
</style>

<div class="calendar icon">
        <div class="header">
            <p class="weekday">
                Monday
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="paper">
            <p class="daynumber">
                7
            </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

### Note:

You would still need to fall back to PNG files (preferably a sprite) and overlay the weekday and the day in any non-webkit browser.

### Disclaimer:

None of this code is mine, it can be found at
http://graphicpeel.com/cssiosicons